# how to send fax (pdf) from the command line using SIP? (Linux)

Tags: sip, fax

I would like to integrate a system with a SIP phone, the system generates pdf files, that should be faxed to specific fax numbers (e.g. sale orders) via SIP. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

The system is run under Linux.
Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with SIP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hylafax](http://www.hylafax.org/content/Main_Page) is what you want to look at. It's the preeminent open source fax server. If you must fax using SIP then make sure your SIP Provider supports [T.38](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/T.38). Without it your faxes will be sent as a standard call with the fax carried over RTP and it only takes a few lost packets here and there to corrupt your fax or cause the transmission to be aborted altogether.